# Can I use New() method in Entity Framework partial classes

Tags: entity-framework

I have extended Entity Framework autogenerated classes with custom partial classes and added several new properties and business login into it. I need to populate those properties any time objects are either materialized from the database or created from scratch without a database contact.

**Can I use or is it advised to use the New() method inside the class for that?** (I know there is an event ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized as well).

As an example, in my partial class i have a property

```
Public Property Employees As List(Of Employee)
```

and I want to instantiate that list somewhere (where?).

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a default constructor for those entities where you set default property values. Notice Entity Framework doesn't create constructors for you, so they can easily be added in partial classes.

Comment: All right, so just using a standard New() method for setting default values is ok also with EF.